# Hibernate: One To One Association without referencing associated object directly

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one

I have currently something like this:

```
public class Particle extends Entity
{
   private Image image;
   ...

   @OneToOne(targetEntity = Image.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "imageId")
   public Image getImage() {
     return image;
   }
}
```

This works fine, but due to another processing, I need the same without referencing the object.
So what I need is actually this:

```
   public class Particle extends Entity
{
   private int imageId;
   ...

   @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "imageId")
   public int getImage() {
     return imageId;
   }
}
```

Obviously I get an exception, which says that Particle class references an unknown entity.
Is there a way, to just provide a id as FK to image, instead of setting the object directly ? 
In the database table, the imageId is already an integer column.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by using `@SecondaryTable` ([documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/SecondaryTable.html))

It would look something like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "particle")
@SecondaryTable(name = "image", pkJoinColumns=@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="imageId"))
public class Particle extends Entity {
    ...
    @Column(table="image", name="imageId")
    public int getImageId() {
        return imageId;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thx a lot. I tried it, but it does not do, what I had expected. this adds a newly constraint to Image object, as hibernate cannot find the particle. But maybe my question wasn't that clear enough, to make that clear. I want to be able to insert images without providing a particle object. But if I insert a particle object, there must be an image to refer to it. So i think that a One-to-One Mapping isnt suitable in this case. how can I achieve this.

Comment: and the image object in particle object should be defined only as an integer, as sstated in question.